# jQuery Selectors or 'if' trouble

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, jquery-selectors

This code should prohibit clicking more than two radiobuttons in total (there are three groups of such buttons).

This works when there is no container **'label'**, but when it is, it doesn't work (it looks like that **'if'** construct is not working; everything that is written outside of it works fine)

**how to make it work without removing the label?** Is there any solutions?

```js
var radio_limit = 2;

$('.pricing-levels-3 label input').on('change', function(evt) {

   if($(this).siblings(':checked').length >= radio_limit) {
       this.checked = false;
   };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="pricing-levels-3">
         <p><strong>Select 2 Levels</strong></p>
         <label>
           <input type="radio" name="vehicle" value="1">Level 1<br>
           <input type="radio" name="vehicle" value="2">Level 2<br>
           <input type="radio" name="vehicle" value="3">Level 3<br>
         </label>
         <label>
           <br>
           <input type="radio" name="vehicle2" value="1">Level 1<br>
           <input type="radio" name="vehicle2" value="2">Level 2<br>
           <input type="radio" name="vehicle2" value="3">Level 3<br>
         </label>
         <label>
           <br>
           <input type="radio" name="vehicle3" value="1">Level 1<br>
           <input type="radio" name="vehicle3" value="2">Level 2<br>
           <input type="radio" name="vehicle3" value="3">Level 3<br>
           <br>
         </label>
</div>
```

Comment: The HTML is invalid because labels can only contain one descendant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for siblings, which they were without labels. Now with labels they are not sibling they are cousins. To fix we read all radio buttons in same div using closest(). Also use prop to check a radio button. Do this:

```
var radio_limit = 2;

$('.pricing-levels-3 label input').on('change', function(evt) {

   if($(this).closest('div').find('input:checked').length >= radio_limit) {
       $(this).prop('checked', false);
   };
});
```